# Enter fullscreen on page load without human intervention

Tags: html5-fullscreen

I'm automating a process for myself (it's not going to be used by public) where as soon as browser starts it'll load our site & should go full screen without any user action.

HTML5 Fullscreen api works fine if user does any action (eg: user clicks a button then site goes fullscreen). But i want it on page load.

I had similar issue with video autoplay (videos won't play on page load without user action) but i got it fixed by enabling a setting in chrome flags (chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy).

Do we have any similar solution for auto fullscreen a page? Any browser would be fine.

Comment: [PWA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Progressive/Installable_PWAs)

Comment: @Jarzon I did a sample desktop pwa & defined display: fullscreen but no luck, it simply shows in normal windows. With user action i can make it fullscreen in pwa & normal browser as well (how can i make it fullscreen on page load).

Comment: Yeah PWA have quite a few requirements(https, service workers..), it's not the easiest solution for a local project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Chrome go in fullscreen with `--start-fullscreen` flag added in the desktop shortcut command.

To add a desktop shortcut in Chrome go in the Main menu > More tools > Create shortcut...

After that, you should have a shortcut on you desktop. Right click on it, go on Properties and add the flag at the end in Target on Windows or Command on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm currently using MacOS, here it's taking chrome app to fullscreen which shows address bar etc (which is different from HTML5 fullscreen, which uses whole screen). Can you once confirm the behaviour on other platforms (windows/linux)?